# How to IE navigate trough range and fill range in a loop?

Tags: loops, select, range, explorer

I'm trying to scrape some data off a page. I need specific info , you'll see it in my if. Now i need the macro to go to not just url at "A2", but to open all the links in "A" column in a loop and if conditions are met to fill correspondent "C" column.

I tried with setting i = 1 to 5 and navigate ("A" & i) but i didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Macro1()



Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.navigate Range("A2").Value
IE.Visible = False
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Dim doc As Object
Set doc = IE.document
Dim kur As Variant
kur = doc.getElementsByClassName("properties")(0).firstElementChild.innerText

If InStr(kur, "GTIN") > 0 Or InStr(kur, "EAN") > 0 Or InStr(kur, "UPC") > 0 Or InStr(kur, "Gtin") > 0 Or InStr(kur, "Ean") > 0 Or InStr(kur, "Upc") > 0 Then

Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = kur

Else

End If

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothin

End Sub
```